# analog to digital cplus plus programming

Tags: c++, linux, analog-digital-converter

I'm working on a coding a analog to digital device that include the api and drive to interface with the device.  My question is where can i go online find more source of information to help me understand what to do with the bits in the buffer.

Comment: http://google.com is the ultimate inexhaustible gimme teh codez resource.

Answer (score 3):

Your question relies heavily on the data sheet of the ADC (Analog to Digital Converter) and the communiction method.  Neither of which you supplied.

For example, I am working with a 14-bit ADC that communicated over the SPI Bus to an ARM 7 microcontroller.  The datasheet for the ADC will tell me what the bits are and their order in my "buffer".

The ADC chips can be SPI-Bus connected, or parallel access.  Which is yours?

How do you talk to the device from your Linux box?

You are getting downvotes because you didn't search the web first.  You can get a lot of information by searching for "linux C++ adc" and by searching for the part number of your ADC.